# How can I get a Perl script running inside Apache to display a list of all running processes on the Apache server?

Tags: apache, perl, permissions, system-administration

Inside the perl script I'm running the below

```
my @lines = `ps -ef`;
```

And currently, when I output the array into my browser I can only see the following processes:

```
UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
root 1928 1 0 Feb18 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/abrtd
apache 9198 9121 1 17:23 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /var/www/cgi-bin/tbchecker.pl
apache 9199 9198 0 17:23 ? 00:00:00 ps -ef
```

I think the issue is that the apache user needs to have access to see all the processes running on the server, but am not sure.

Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

(OS is Linux centos 6.4)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that the apache user "needs to have access to see all the processes running on the server" is false (on a well-configured Apache2 server).

It is recommended to run the apache httpd server processes under a special account with restricted priviledges.

If you really want to change this and you know the implications of it, you can configure Apche2 to run under the root account. The Apache documentation on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ is your friend.

Comment: Agreed, I don't want to make apache run under the root account.  But how can I allow the apache user to see all the processes running on the system via the 'ps' command?

Answer (score 0):

There is still the possibility to run the perl script as user root with the SUID bit set. Note that I have not tested whether it will give you the desired output; normal shell scripts can't be run in SUID mode (under Linux, at least) and the shell drops the additional priviledges before executing a command.